# Accessing JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to access JSON data with PHP. I have the following JSON data from an API stored as `$json`.

```
{
    "lat": 33.44,
    "lon": -94.04,
    "timezone": "America\/Chicago",
    "timezone_offset": -21600,
    "current": {
        "dt": 1609797727,
        "sunrise": 1609766440,
        "sunset": 1609802491,
        "temp": 66.2,
        "feels_like": 55.81,
        "pressure": 1018,
        "humidity": 20,
        "dew_point": 24.91,
        "uvi": 0.4,
        "clouds": 1,
        "visibility": 10000,
        "wind_speed": 10.29,
        "wind_deg": 300,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I'm trying to access each item in it. When I try "`echo $json["lat"];`", for example, I don't get anything.

When I try:

```
foreach($json as $data){
    echo $data;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

I get:

```
33.44
-94.04
America/Chicago
-21600
```

Why isn't `echo $json["lat"];` giving 33.44, and why doesn't echo `$json["current"]["temp"];` giving 66.2? How do I access the data correctly?

Comment: How did you parse the JSON? `json_decode($response)` or `json_decode($response, true)`?

Comment: The first returns an object, not an array, so you would need to use `$json->lat`

Comment: Barmar!!! Thank you!!! I needed to put "true" in there. If you answer the question with your comment I'll give you the credit. Thanks!!!